# AngularJS AJAX Status Code Error Handling

Tags: angularjs

I have an interceptor:

```
angular.module('mobileDashboardApp')
    .factory('HTTPInterceptor', function ($rootScope, $q, HTTPErrors) {
        return {
            responseError: function (response) {
                $rootScope.$broadcast({
                    500: HTTPErrors.serverError,
                    503: HTTPErrors.serviceError
                }[response.status], response);
                return $q.reject(response);
            }
        };
    })
```

And the constants are defined here:

```
angular.module('mobileDashboardApp')
    .constant('HTTPErrors', {
        serverError: 'internal-server-error',
        serviceError: 'service-error'
    })
```

How can I run a $rootScope.$on to do a console.log whenever there is a 500 error?

In my config I added the interceptor using:

```
.config(function ($httpProvider, $routeProvider) {
    $httpProvider.interceptors.push([
        '$injector',
        function ($injector) {
            return $injector.get('HTTPInterceptor');
        }
    ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you're broadcasting an `HTTPErrors.serverError` string event on 500 status and `HTTPErrors.serviceError` string event on 503 status. So you can catch them by having this code on whichever controller you want subscribed to these events

```
$rootScope.$on(HTTPErrors.serverError, function(event, args){
    console.log("500");
});
$rootScope.$on(HTTPErrors.serviceError, function(event, args){
    console.log("503");
});
```

of course you need to inject `HTTPErrors` into that controller.